# Convergence of indicator random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Let $ (\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P) $ be a probability space and $A_n$ be a sequence of events such that $P(A_n) \leq 2^{-n}$. Let $ \{ X_n := 1_{A_n} \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $. 
It is then true that $ X_{n} \rightarrow_{P} 0 $ (as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2658533/consequence-of-convergence-of-indicator-function-to-zero-in-probability)
for instance).
 Is it also true that $X_n \rightarrow 0$  a.s. ? If not, what is a counterxample?

Comment: **Hint:** $\Bbb E[\sum X_n]=\sum\Bbb E[X_n]<\infty,$ so $\sum X_n<\infty$ almost surely.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Ok so now I just use the basic fact that if a series converges then the sequence of terms must go to $0$ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ one has $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(|X_n|>\epsilon) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X_n=1) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty P(A_n) \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}<\infty.$$ By the Borel Cantelli lemma one has $X_n \to 0$, a.s.